# Cannot deserialize XML object to data class using JacksonXml

Tags: xml, kotlin, jackson, xml-deserialization, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm attempting to deserialize this xml string:

```
val xml2 = """
  <id>3</id>
""".trimIndent()
```

to this data class

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "id")
data class Id(
//    @field:JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
//    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
//    val attribute: String? = null,
    @JacksonXmlText
    val value: Int
)
```

but every time I attempt to do so by doing this

```
println(JacksonXml.asA<Id>(xml2))
```

I get this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid definition for property ''
```

Why can I not make use of the `@JacksonXmlText` annotation? My intention is to figure out how to deserialize xml strings that look like this:

```
<id attribute="Pig">3</id>
```

but I can't even get the `@JacksonXmlText` annotation to work on its own, so is there a workaround that would allow me to accomplish the same thing without making use of `@JacksonXmlText`?

Answer (score 0):

Can u try this sample? it works for me.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "id")
data class Id(
    //Your fields
) {
  @JacksonXmlText
  val value: Int? = 0
}
```